# Is [$x$] monotonically increasing?(where $[x]$ means greatest integer function)

Tags: calculus, functions

Is [$x$] monotonically increasing? (where $[x]$ means greatest integer function). In my book it is given as non monotonically increasing function. But I think it is monotonically increasing function. Please clarify me.
[image]

Comment: Yes, of course it is.

Comment: Depending on your terminology (and terminology/definitions are *not always* universal), one may say that this function is *monotonoically increasing* but is not *strictly monotonically increasing*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

Informally: The floor function never decreases (it is either constant or increases strictly).

Formally: $[x] \leq [x]+1 = [x+1]$ so by definition the floor function is increasing.